# running ruby system() from rails server including gem access

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I realize the peril I am asking for, but I am setting up a ruby on rails server on a mac using Big Sur to give students access to remote robots they will be able to see with a webcam.

This first one is allowing students to use a ruby library to control the robot. They enter the source code to run through the browser, which is stored in sketch.source_code.

After saving the record in the normal way and writing the source to the filesystem, this code runs on the rails server to try to execute the robot control code:

```
source_pathname = "/tmp/code.rb"
output_pathname = "/tmp/code.log"

File.write(source_pathname, sketch.source_code) # write the code to execute to the filesystem

env = {}
env['GEM_PATH'] = '/Users/fmorton/.gems:/Users/fmorton/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/Users/fmorton/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0'

ruby = "ruby #{source_pathname} &>#{output_pathname}"

result = system(env, ruby)
```

This works fine if the original source code includes the full path to the gem, as in:

require '/Users/fmorton/.gems/gems/birdbrain-0.9.4/lib/birdbrain.rb'

But, if specifying the gem as in:

require 'birdbrain'

the gem is not found.

Comment: I guess the `GEM_PATH` from the Ruby subprocess is differet from the one in the calling Ruby? Otherwise there would be no need to pass it via `env`.

Comment: Seems like your gem is installed on different ruby version. What is your ruby version for rails server?

Comment: I have verified that the rails server and the "system" process are using the exact same path to ruby (using "which") and also verified using "gem env" in both situations that the GEM_PATHS are set the same. I'm still stuck and willing to try any suggestion.

Comment: I have now figured out that the gem is being left out of the $LOAD_PATH for some reason. There are a lot of gems in the $LOAD_PATH, but not the specific gem I need. If I add "-I /Users/fmorton/.gems/gems/birdbrain-0.9.4/lib" to the ruby command line, it gets placed in the $LOAD_PATH and all is good. I don't want to have to do this, so if anyone knows why it would be left out of the $LOAD_PATH would be helpful and appreciated.